# No "New" Link on Calendar View

Tags: 2010, calendar

I made a custom Sharepoint 2010 list and then made a Calendar view for the list. When I view the calender, however, I don't get a link to add a new entry on the calendar like I do for the default calendar. I saw [this suggestion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/sharepoint2010general/thread/5f623982-27eb-4062-b9ce-6203cbabb3cf) but I don't know how to change the type. I am only using Sharepoint Designer. What should I do?

Answer (score 8):

You have created a Calendar View in an existing list which was not created from Calendar List template. So the new option is not available. New option is available as usual from the Items Tab.

The link that you referred started with events list template so he gets the link to add new event in a calendar.

Answer (score 0):

The question here is how to get the Add link in the new calendar.  Perhaps this calendar has to be a custom list instead of one made from the default available Calendar List. (Like the one I am working with when I found this post)  It has to be so because the client wants specific form behavior that I cannot get unless I alter the base Calendar List forms (Sharepoint tells me they are specifically locked).  But that would alter other lists on the installation, which the client does not want to happen.  What to do?  Make a new custom list so you have full form control.  But then you encounter this issue, as stated by skaz.  Sorry for the short rant there, but I found Ashish's post to only state the observation that we already have, and to offer nothing.

From the Office knowledge base: "The view itself is not directly customizable using the available view editing and WYSIWYG editing tools in SharePoint Designer 2010. To change the appearance of these views, you need to use code view or a developer application, like Visual Studio."  So lets go hunting in some code.

In the lower left of Sharepoint Designer's display of the calendar, there are three options:
Design, Split, and Code.
Using the code option/interface I am able to see the pre-render guts of the calendar view, but it looks the same as the one created with a Calendar List list.

Looking at the solution in the link in the original question and this one, [at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959912), appear to be the same but no one says what file it goes in.  It does not go in the calendar code (found that out).  Doing some Googling, I find the definition of the ListTemplate element: "Specifies a list definition that is available as an option for creating lists on the Create page."  This tells me that it should be somewhere at the root of my custom list.  The All Files option in Designer does not show me any file I did not already know existed in the list (forms and this calendar).  A little more reading (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office) shows me that this element is supposed to go in the Schema.xml file that defines the list I am working with.  I made this list with the UI (silly me, being an open source developer trying to do a favor in a Microsoft world) and have not found the Schema.xml file in the list folder.

Enough people say this is the solution (for Sharepoint 2010 anyway) that it should be the solution, if only I could find where that Schema.xml went to.  I bet the gremlins hid it... time to go hunting.